# Android close PopUp

Tags: android, popup, hide, dismiss

how can i close the PopUp when a button is clicked?

`.dismiss();` and `.cancel();` dont works for me or i make something wrong.

```
    //Game Paused PopUp
private void PauseMenu() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pause_menu, null);
    helpBuilder.setView(popupView);
    Button resume = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.resume);

    resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Close PopUp
        }
    });

    AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    helpDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    PauseMenu();
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

**And please dont vote down without a comment!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void PauseMenu() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pause_menu, null);
    helpBuilder.setView(popupView);
    Button resume = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.resume);

    final AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            helpDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    helpDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    PauseMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to retain a reference to the dialog in order to dismiss it.

The following should work:

```
private void displayPauseMenu() { // method names are always lower-case!!

    final AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pause_menu, null);
    helpBuilder.setView(popupView);

    // this is what you need to dismiss
    final AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    Button resume = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.resume);

    resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            helpDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    helpDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    displayPauseMenu();
}
```